# Python - read parquet file without pandas

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

Currently I'm using the code below on `Python 3.5, Windows` to read in a `parquet` file.

```
import pandas as pd

parquetfilename = 'File1.parquet'
parquetFile = pd.read_parquet(parquetfilename, columns=['column1', 'column2'])
```

However, I'd like to do so without using pandas. How to best do this? I'm using both `Python 2.7 and 3.6` on `Windows`.

Comment: https://github.com/jcrobak/parquet-python

Comment: What about the pyarrow.parquet library? [link](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html) As a matter of curiosity, why don't you want to use pandas?

Comment: @user2413548, I've already tried this out. But I can't seem to install parquet on both 2.7 and 3.6.

Comment: @UncleBenBen pandas is a bulky module and difficult to install on aws lambda, hence I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: use virtualenv to support both 2.7 and 3.6

Comment: @user2413548 That's not the issue.

Comment: @inquisitiveProgrammer did you try this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45147779/1552998

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`duckdb`](https://duckdb.org/) for this. It's an embedded RDBMS similar to SQLite but with OLAP in mind. There's a nice Python API and a SQL function to import Parquet files:

```py
import duckdb

conn = duckdb.connect(":memory:") # or a file name to persist the DB

# Keep in mind this doesn't support partitioned datasets,
# so you can only read one partition at a time
conn.execute("CREATE TABLE mydata AS SELECT * FROM parquet_scan('/path/to/mydata.parquet')")

# Export a query as CSV
conn.execute("COPY (SELECT * FROM mydata WHERE col = 'val') TO 'col_val.csv' WITH (HEADER 1, DELIMITER ',')")
```