# How do I read partitioned parquet files from s3 using pyarrow?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parquet, pyarrow

I'm trying to read a partitioned parquet directory stored in an s3 bucket.

For the sake of this question, let's call the bucket `bucket`. The bucket has one folder which has subsequent partitions based on year/month/day/hour.

So, if a .parquet file was to be reached, the url would be:

`s3://bucket/folder/year/month/day/hour`

I tried to read it as I would do for any other parquet file. I've been working with them recently. However, I hadn't tried reading a partitioned file so far.

I've included my sample code below:

```
import s3fs
import pandas as pd
import boto3

# Creating an S3 Filesystem (Only required when using S3)

s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
s3_path = "s3://bucket"
directory = 'folder'

# Loading Files (S3)

data = pq.ParquetDataset(f'{s3_path}/{directory}', filesystem = s3).read_pandas().to_pandas()
```

This is the flow I've used and I know it works for general parquet files. Now, the error that I get is this:

`ValueError: Directory name did not appear to be a partition: 2019`

I've already tried to dive into `2019` since I figured that the first level only had `2019` as a folder so it might think it was a subdirectory and not a partition.

The path then looked like `s3://bucket/folder/2019`

However, that gave me the following error, along similar lines:

`ValueError: Directory name did not appear to be a partition: 05`

I've also tried using `fastparquet` following an approach from this question: [How to read partitioned parquet files from S3 using pyarrow in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45082832/how-to-read-partitioned-parquet-files-from-s3-using-pyarrow-in-python)

That didn't work either. If I tried printing the list of files using the `all_paths_from_s3` from the answer to the question above, it gave me a blank list `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because the partitioning path should look like this:

> s3://bucket/folder/year=2019/month=05/day=01

If you are using *Kinesis Firehose* to persist the data to the S3 buckets (for example), you can use the **prefix** option to override the default AWS *year/month/day/hour* format.

Comment: This was exactly it! Thank you so much!