# Write pandas dataframe to parquet in s3 AWS

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parquet

I want to write my dataframe in my s3 bucket in a parquet format. 
I know how to write the dataframe in a csv format. But I don't know how to write in parquet format. 
Here is the code for the csv format (I don't display the fields ServerSideEncryption and SSEKMSKeyId but I use them in my actual code ) :

```
csv_to_write = df.to_csv(None).encode()
s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name,Key='data.csv', Body=csv_to_write,
              ServerSideEncryption='XXXXX', SSEKMSKeyId='XXXXXXXX')
```

Does someone have the equivalent for parquet ? 
Thanks

Comment: Looks like this function is what your are looking for:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html

Answer (score 12):

For python 3.6+, AWS has a library called [aws-data-wrangler](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler) that helps with the integration between Pandas/S3/Parquet

to install do;

```
pip install awswrangler
```

if you want to write your pandas dataframe as a parquet file to S3 do;

```
import awswrangler as wr
wr.s3.to_parquet(
    df=df,
    path="s3://my-bucket/key/my-file.parquet"
)
```

if you want to add encryption do;

```
import awswrangler as wr
extra_args = {
    "ServerSideEncryption": "aws:kms",
    "SSEKMSKeyId": "YOUR_KMS_KEY_ARN"
}
sess = wr.Session(s3_additional_kwargs=extra_args)
sess.s3.to_parquet(
    df=df,
    path="s3://my-bucket/key/my-file.parquet"
)
```

Comment: I don't know the history so didn't want to do an edit, but I think the API might have changed since this post?  See [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler#quick-start).  Instead of `wr.pandas.to_parquet` I think you use `wr.s3.to_parquet`.  Otherwise though, this solution is **fantastic**.  Can even authenticate via in one command via `to_parquet(..., s3_additional_kwargs = dict(aws_access_key_id=..., aws_secret_access_key=...))`

Comment: Thanks @Andrew and you are right. As of version 1.0.0 awswrangler uses `wr.s3.to_parquet` instead of `wr.pandas.to_parquet`, hence I updated my answer.

Comment: It looks like in a recent version of awswrangler, the correct parameter to the `to_parquet()` method is `df`, not `dataframe`.

https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.s3.to_parquet.html

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your dataframe is called df, use the following code to first convert it to parquet format and store it. Then upload this parquet file on s3.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import boto3

parquet_table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_table(parquet_table, local_file_name)

s3 = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id='XXX',aws_secret_access_key='XXX')
s3.upload_file(local_file_name, bucket_name, remote_file_name)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I got this error while running this line [parquet_table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)] :  [TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)]
Do you know how I can solve this ?

Comment: Please check the column types of your dataframe and make sure none of them has type "object". pandas allow different types in a single column and parquet does not like this. Try to get the object columns with  ```obj_cols = df.select_dtypes('object').columns``` then convert each to an appropriate type.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent solution above with use of AWS Wrangler, but I did get an error when I attempted to use example above, assuming the lib has changed.  The following worked for me:

```
wr.s3.to_parquet(df, path=f"s3://{output_bucket}/{output_key}.parquet", index=False)
```