# How to read parquet file data partitioned on column from AWS S3 using python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, parquet

I have saved the below table using pyspark to AWS S3, partitioned by column "channel_name". using below code.

```
 df.write.option("header",True) \
                .partitionBy("channel_name") \
                .mode('append')\
                .parquet("s3://path")
```

| start_timestamp | channel_name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-11-02 08:51:50 | velocity | 1 |
| 2020-11-02 09:14:29 | Temp | 0 |
| 2020-11-02 09:18:32 | velocity | 0 |
| 2020-11-02 09:32:42 | velocity | 4 |
| 2020-11-03 13:06:03 | Temp | 2 |
| 2020-11-03 13:10:01 | Temp | 1 |
| 2020-11-03 13:54:38 | Temp | 5 |
| 2020-11-03 14:46:25 | velocity | 5 |
| 2020-11-03 14:57:31 | Kilometer | 6 |
| 2020-11-03 15:07:07 | Kilometer | 7 |

But i want to read same data which is partitoned on column "channel_name" using python, its not working, it is excluding that partitioned column "channel_name". below is code i tried with AWSwrangler.

```
import awswrangler as wr
df = wr.s3.read_parquet(path="s3://shreyasbigdata/Prod_test_item_id=V214944/")
```

It looks like this, but i want that "channel_name" column also.

| start_timestamp | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-11-02 08:51:50 | 1 |
| 2020-11-02 09:14:29 | 0 |
| 2020-11-02 09:18:32 | 0 |
| 2020-11-02 09:32:42 | 4 |
| 2020-11-03 13:06:03 | 2 |
| 2020-11-03 13:10:01 | 1 |
| 2020-11-03 13:54:38 | 5 |
| 2020-11-03 14:46:25 | 5 |
| 2020-11-03 14:57:31 | 6 |
| 2020-11-03 15:07:07 | 7 |

I tried with different libraries but its not working.
Would be great if you help me to read all the columns including partitioned one.

Answer (score 0):

## I got the Answer thank you

```
import s3fs
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

bucket = 'bucket_name'
path = 'path_of_folder' #if its a directory omit the traling /
bucket_uri = f's3://{bucket}/{path}'

dataset = pq.ParquetDataset(bucket_uri, filesystem=fs)
table = dataset.read()
df = table.to_pandas()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: found this answer at following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45082832/how-to-read-partitioned-parquet-files-from-s3-using-pyarrow-in-python