# Is it a bug in fastparquet module

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker, fastparquet

I am using AWS sagemaker Jupiter notebook and getting following error:

```
<ipython-input-42-14cd1ee49f9c> in <module>()
      1 import s3fs
----> 2 import fastparquet as fp
      3 s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
      4 fs = s3fs.core.S3FileSystem()
      5 

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastparquet/__init__.py in <module>()
      6 
      7 from .thrift_structures import parquet_thrift
----> 8 from .core import read_thrift
      9 from .writer import write
     10 from . import core, schema, converted_types, api

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastparquet/core.py in <module>()
     12 
     13 from . import encoding
---> 14 from .compression import decompress_data
     15 from .converted_types import convert, typemap
     16 from .schema import _is_list_like, _is_map_like

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastparquet/compression.py in <module>()
     43     def snappy_decompress(data, uncompressed_size):
     44         return snappy.decompress(data)
---> 45     compressions['SNAPPY'] = snappy.compress
     46     decompressions['SNAPPY'] = snappy_decompress
     47 except ImportError:

AttributeError: module 'snappy' has no attribute 'compress'
```

I noticed that the attribute is named snappy.compress. Shouldn't it be snappy_compress with underscore?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using Amazon SageMaker.

This does not look like an issue with Amazon SageMaker. You might find answer on this [Error with snappy while importing fastparquet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44301238/error-with-snappy-while-importing-fastparquet-in-python/44310390) post useful.

Hope this helps.